# Use the Python console to write layer name in attribute table

Tags: pyqgis, field-calculator, qgis-python-console

The task I would like to solve is to write an individual shapefile's name into a new column of its attribute table for all shapefiles in a given directory.

My current - disfunctional - code looks like this:

```
import glob, os, processing
input_path = "/home/me/Folder/"
for layer in glob.glob(input_path + "*.shp"):
   processing.runalg("qgis:fieldcalculator", layer, 'columnname', 2, 25.0, 3.0, True, '@layer_name', os.path.basename(layer) + *_new.shp")
```

This results, so far, in an indentation error pointing to the last element of the algorithm's elements.

---

Using Joseph's code provided below (copied from a text editor into the Python console), the algorithm runs over one shapefile, writes the shapefile's name *including* the `.shp`-ending into a column, then ends abruptly with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 3, in <module>
  File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/tools/general.py", line 75, in runalg
    alg = Processing.runAlgorithm(algOrName, None, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/core/Processing.py", line 257, in runAlgorithm
    if not param.setValue(args[i]):
  File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/core/parameters.py", line 997, in setValue
    self.value = unicode(obj)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 88: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The names to be written contain German *Umlaute*, could this cause any problems of this kind?

---

After removing the *Umlaute*, I ran this code:

```
import glob, os, processing
input_path = "/Some/Folder/"
for layer in glob.glob(input_path + "*.shp"):
    output = "/Some/Folder/Subfolder/" + os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(layer))[0] + "_withName.shp"
    processing.runalg("qgis:fieldcalculator", layer, 'Name', 2, 25.0, 0, 1,  '@layer_name', output)
```

The result is almost as it should be except for the layers' names written into the attribute table still having the `.shp`-ending. What's wrong with the field calculator command here?

---

Following Joseph's advice, the code that eventually did the trick was:

```
import glob, os, processing
input_path = "/Some/Folder/"
for layer in glob.glob(input_path + "*.shp"):
    output = "/Some/Folder/Subfolder/" + os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(layer))[0] + "_withName.shp"
    processing.runalg("qgis:fieldcalculator", layer, 'Name', 2, 25.0, 0, 1,  """ replace(@layer_name,'.shp','') """, output)
```

As far as I can tell, the `replace`-command works like this: `replace(@layer_name, 'bit to be replace', 'bit to replace it with')` - but what exactly are the triple quotes for, Joseph?

Comment: See original post, sorry for the omission.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by _"the saved names still having the .shp-ending"_. All files have this ending? Can you give an example of an output filename?

Comment: Now that I re-read my question, I formulated it unclearly. What I actually meant was that the _layer's name written as an attribute into the newly-created column_ still contained said ending. Therefore, the question is how to tweak the field calculator's action in order to write `Name` into the attribute table instead of `Name.shp`.

Comment: Very strange issue, try replacing your `'@layer_name'` expression with this expression (note the triple quotes): `""" replace(@layer_name,'.shp','') """`

Comment: This worked, thank you Joseph. If you have the time, please educate me on the function of the triple quotes.

Comment: Triple quotes basically allows you to include additional strings within it (which is required for the expression `""" replace(@layer_name,'.shp','') """`). If we used single quotes, we would need to escape the quotes and it becomes quite messy. Personally, I like surrounding the expression with triple quotes because you can use the same expression within QGIS :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually when you indent, you use four spaces. Also I think there's a typo in the following line:

```
os.path.basename(layer) + *_new.shp"
```

Where you used `*` instead of `"`. But this is just giving the output filename. Instead, you need to give it a full path **including** the new filename.

So you could try using something like the following:

```
import glob, os, processing
input_path = "/home/me/Folder/"
for layer in glob.glob(input_path + "*.shp"):
    output = input_path + os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(layer))[0] + "_new.shp"
    processing.runalg("qgis:fieldcalculator", layer, 'columnname', 2, 25.0, 3.0, True, '@layer_name', output)
```

---

Note that the code above saves the output in the same directory as the input. If you want to change this, replace `input_path` in the `output` parameter. E.g:

```
output = "another/path/" + os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(layer))[0] + "_new.shp"
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the console gives me another indentation error after entering the first element (`output...`) of the `for`-loop in your example. Any idea as to why?

Comment: @T.K. - Are you copying/pasting the code directly into your python console or into a text editor first?

Comment: Directly into my Python console, while changing the individual details (path names).

Comment: @T.K. Please do not post additional questions as comments

Comment: @T.K. - I suggest copying/pasting the above code into a text editor like Notepad, the indentation should still be valid, make the changes to the details, then paste the whole thing into the python console. Otherwise, please [edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/241375/edit) your question to include your progress so far :)

Comment: @Joseph: Done, see above.

Comment: @T.K. - Just noticed your edit, I think you're right in that the unicode error is likely due to your shapefile names containing non-ASCII characters. Try renaming them without the accents and run the code again.

Comment: I did and the code ran smoothly, please see the latest edit for the last missing piece.